# Batch File Cannot Execute command in Windows 2003 server

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I cannot execute command line command on Windows 2003 server.

Below is the path which i put in notepad and save it as .bat and RUN it doesnt help.

D:\Program Files(x86)\PH\Check This 7.11\ASD\ABC>sm -reportlic > D:\srini\test1.txt

Above command helps me to execute the command from dos prompt and save results in txt file to D:\ drive at mentioned path.

But cant create a batch file to execute the same.

Please help any assistance will be appreciated.

Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change to the proper drive and folder to execute `sm` first, or call it directly using a full path. In either case, you need to quote the path because it contains spaces.

Changing drive and directory first:

```
cd /d "D:\Program Files(x86)\PH\Check This 7.11\ASD\ABC"
sm -reportlic > D:\srini\test1.txt
```

Using a full path:

```
"D:\Program Files(x86)\PH\Check This 7.11\ASD\ABC>sm" -reportlic > D:\srini\test1.txt
```